# Loading semantic ui icons into CefSharp

Tags: c#, .net, semantic-ui, cefsharp

I am using CEFSharp with a LocalSchemeHandler. 
I have the following directory structure in a css directory.

```
semantic-2.1.8.min.css
icon.min.css
themes
  -- default
       -- assets
            -- fonts
                 icons.eot
                 icons.otf
                 icons.svg
                 icons.ttf
                 icons.woff
```

My html page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="../css/semantic-2.1.8.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/semantic-2.1.8.min.js"></script>
...
```

I make a request of semantic like this

```
 iconElm.addClass("star half empty red");
```

an empty red box will be displayed.

By VS debugging I have determined that the semantic css file is requested, and semantic loads in the page. The icon files aren't requested, and don't display.

Comment: What does `DevTools` say?

Comment: Sorry @amaitland, been away. I don't see any errors in devTools. The fonts are loaded correctly but, according to the log, they were actually requested from https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/H2DMvhDLycM56KNuAtbJYA.woff2